# Iterator and const_iterator operator++ post and prefix

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading, prefix-operator

We are working on a custom List class. We are trying to implement iterator and const_iterator and its functions but we have a problem with our ++operators. PostFix doesn't work at all, and PreFix gives us segfault when we step too far (the current code is a workaround that just returns the last valid result).
Question1: How can we fix the segfault related to prefix without returning last valid element? (we have tried returning nullptr).

Postfix just wont iterate, even though we have followed every guide on the internet <.<

Question2: Why doesn't PostFix work?

Code for post&prefix:

```
List_const_iterator_& operator++()
  {
    if(ptr->next_ != nullptr)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next_;
        return *this;
    }
    else
        return *this;
  }

  List_const_iterator_ operator++(int unused)
  {
    List_const_iterator_ temp(*this);
    if(ptr->next_ != nullptr)
    {
      ptr = ptr->next_;
      return temp;
    }
    else
      return *this;
  }
```

Testcode (atm with postfix):

```
List<int> list1 {324, 2, 3};
  List_const_iterator_<int> clst = list1.cbegin();
  clst = clst++;
  cout << "val: " << clst.ptr->data_ << endl;
  clst = clst++;
  cout << "val2: " << clst.ptr->data_ << endl;
 clst = clst++;
  cout << "val3: " << clst.ptr->data_ << endl;
```

Output for postfix:

```
val: 324
val2: 324
val3: 324
```

Output for prefix:

```
val: 2
val2: 3
val3: 3  <-- This is where we segfault if we don't use the controll.
```

Comment: Given that the postfix operator returns the old value, what do you expect from `clst = clst++;` (except undefined behaviour)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with just :

```
clst++;
```

instead of :

```
clst = clst++;
```

The latter resets `clst` to its original value (as if the increment didn't happen).

Comment: Yeah, that solved it!
Do you have any ideas on what we should do if iteration reaches the end of our list? because just returning the last valid value doesn't seem like a very good fix in the long run =)

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson I think you should do the same as the standard library and let that be undefined (i.e. just fail miserably). The iteration should be bounded by by the caller by comparison to an "end" iterator.

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson : your iterator should compare equal to `list1.cend()` when it has reached the end of `list1`. So, you can then check against that, eg. `for (it = list1.cbegin(); it != list1.cend(); ++it) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: However bad, `clst = clst++;` is not undefined. You even [said it yourself.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22940999/947836) :)

Comment: @jrok : indeed - shame on me for realizing this is not the `++` operator, but a function call. I blame my brain's pattern matching engine.